# Add hue to Seaborn Histogram annotation

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotations, seaborn, histogram

I have a snippet of code that produces 2 `seaborn.histogram` plots on the same axes, split by `hue`, and annotated:

[image]

The two histograms are appropriately colored differently using the `hue` parameter, and the count of data in each bin are also appropriately annotated. However, can I also color the **annotations / counts of what is in each bin**?

Current [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):

```
np.random.seed(8)
t = pd.DataFrame(
    {
    'Value': np.random.uniform(low=100000, high=500000, size=(50,)), 
    'Type': ['B' if x < 6 else 'R' for x in np.random.uniform(low=1, high=10, size=(50,))] 
    }
)

ax = sns.histplot(data=t, x='Value', bins=5, hue='Type', palette="dark")
ax.set(title="R against B")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.0f'))
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate(f'{p.get_height():.0f}\n',
                (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2, p.get_height()), ha='center', va='center', color='crimson')        
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_facecolor`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.get_facecolor.html) *method*.

This way, you can match the color of each annotation with the color of the corresponding histo.

```
for p in ax.patches:
    color = p.get_facecolor()
    ax.annotate(f"{p.get_height():.0f}\n", (p.get_x() + p.get_width() / 2, p.get_height()),
                ha="center", va="center", color=color, fontweight="bold")
```

Output :

[image]